# In my flutter with block, it is not re-rendered a second time

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a small test application for myself to understand how the block works with ListView. I wrote such a program. (Sorry that everything is in one file, this is for clarity).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

enum NoteEvent {
  onState,
  offState,
  changeState,
  StartDataUpdate,
}

class NoteBloc extends Bloc<NoteEvent, Note> {
  Note thisNote = Note(check: true, title: '0', index: 0);
  Note get initialState => initialState;

  NoteBloc(Note initialState)
      : thisNote = initialState,
        super(initialState);

  @override
  Stream<Note> mapEventToState(NoteEvent event) async* {
    if (event == NoteEvent.onState) {
      this.thisNote.check = true;
    } else if (event == NoteEvent.offState) {
      this.thisNote.check = false;
    }
    yield this.thisNote;
  }
}

class Note {
  final int index;
  String title;
  bool check;
  Note({
    required this.index,
    required this.title,
    required this.check,
  });
}

List list = [
  Note(index: 0, title: '0', check: true),
  Note(index: 1, title: '1', check: true),
  Note(index: 2, title: '2', check: false),
  Note(index: 3, title: '3', check: false),
  Note(index: 4, title: '4', check: true),
  Note(index: 5, title: '5', check: true),
  Note(index: 6, title: '6', check: false),
  Note(index: 7, title: '7', check: false),
  Note(index: 8, title: '8', check: true),
  Note(index: 9, title: '9', check: true),
];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('bloc_list_view')),
            body: ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return BlocProvider(
                    create: (context) => NoteBloc(list[index]),
                    child: BlocBuilder<NoteBloc, Note>(
                      builder: (context, note) {
                        print(note);
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                            value: note.check,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              print(value);
                              if (value == true)
                                BlocProvider.of<NoteBloc>(context)
                                    .add(NoteEvent.onState);
                              else if (value == false)
                                BlocProvider.of<NoteBloc>(context)
                                    .add(NoteEvent.offState);
                            },
                            title: Text(note.title));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10),
                itemCount: list.length)));
  }
}
```

Ideally, you should just get a list of 10 listtiles, clicking on which the CheckBox would change its value.
***Problem***.
ListTile changes the value only once, the second and subsequent times nothing happens. I read on the Internet that it is necessary to use equitable, but this works in cases where an existing render will be ignored, and my case is different.
Please give a detailed answer on how to make flutter re-render the same thing several times.

Answer (score 1):

And here I am, having gained experience, answering my own question 8 months later)
The problem was that when comparing the two classes, the BLoC did not find the difference and did not re-render the screen.
To do this, you need to use Equitable (https://pub.dev/packages/equatable ).
With the help of a mixin, you can specify the props by which class comparisons will take place!

Although if I had a time machine, I would go back 8 months ago and ask why I use the BLoC here..)